# prozgui not downloading larger files?

Tags: 12.04, download-manager

downloading larger files using prozgui which is  integrated with firefox by flashgot in ubuntu 12.04 gives following error :
Not enough storage space or storage media fails to create file

i am using ubuntu 12.04 32 bit with gnome shell

please help nad sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have enough space left in your drive. You can verify this by checking free space left in your drive. In case the problem is with download manager, you can try some other downloader like [FlareGet](http://flareget.com/download), DownThemAll or some other.

Comment: it's not the case as other download manager are working well